# Polulating field inside array of object array

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

My model looks like this:

```
const gallerySchema = new Schema({
  pictures: [[{
    title: String,
    file: {
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'asset',
    }
  }]],
  createdAt: Date
});
```

I want to populate the `file` field.

I tried this

```
Gallery
.find({})
.populate({'path': 'pictures.file'})
```

This didn't work.

Comment: why do you have array inside another array, you should have added an object with an array field to it. this will it will be easier to write most of the queries